# Undo changes made to files in /usr/bin/

Tags: linux, kali-linux, system-recovery

I am new to linux
I have a Kali 2.0. I was trying to install jdk 8 on it. 
I couldn't do it via terminal.
I downloaded the jdk package from Java website and extracted it using tar -xf to my home directory
Added the directory containing javac to my path variable permanently.
And I removed the existing Java 1.7 
It said something like /usr/bin/javac missing.
I guess I was feeling really stupid but I copied all the files from the jdk folder I downloaded onto /usr/bin/  and tried the javac command.
This time it said some lib file wasn't found so I opened each folder from the jdk folder I downloaded and copied all the files and not the folders from each folder onto the /usr/bin/ directory.
I have no idea what I did but now when I try to install the old jdk I had (using apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk) it gets installed but then when I try javac , I get the same message some lib file is missing.
Could someone please tell me what I did to my system and how can I fix it?

Comment: Did you remove the existing `Java 1.7` package using `apt-get`?

Comment: Yes I did remove it.

Comment: What happened when you tried installing JDK 8? I see `openjdk-8` in their repositories. http://pkg.kali.org/pkg/openjdk-8

Comment: It said it didn't exist when I tried that command

Comment: I tried apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk because that was the command for 1.7. and that worked so I thought the command for 8 would be similar.

Answer (score 0):

I still have no idea on what effect adding extra files and replacing files at /usr/bin will do. I guess I'll have to wait and see whether applications will start to crash or not and repair them.

But here is the good news, I finally got the jdk8 installed.
Since no other way was work for me.. I made a link to the javac file in the original file that I externally downloaded onto my home directory and placed this link in /usr/bin/ directory and renamed the link as javac and deleted the javac I copied onto the directory earlier.
And guess what.. it worked.